# Using the same subjects in different measures

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

I'm working on an experiment where I collect 3 categories of reaction time data form subjects who are video game players, distinguished by the game that they play (eg. RTS, FPS, MOBA). I wish to compare the group differences based how performance indicated by the reaction time categories might contribute to their game success (eg. achived ranks or ELO points). I was given the advice that I could increase the subject count if I allow for subjects to be placed in more than one group in case they play multiple games. Isn't this method contraproductive when I compare these groups because such a player would be compared with him/herself? Or it can be still useful, but only if I don't compare game genres but low vs high ELO subjects?

Comment: Are ELO scores comparable across games?

Comment: I use ranks as a proxy for that, then I normalize them.